# "StackOverflow is fast. Very, very fast." Why and how?

Tags: discussion, performance

In the "About" section of SO, it says that it is "Fast. Very, very fast."

What is it that makes it so fast? DB? MVC? What?

Comment: What do you consider fast. For me on a 100MBit net, a listing page HTML only download takes 1.42seconds. Thats pretty slow in my standards.

Comment: I think he is asking because the site specificly states that it is very very fast.

Comment: We'll, I answered the wrong question....

Comment: Lots and lots of little imps which operate all the machinery behind the curtain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/10370#10370) lies everything that StackOverflow is built with. Using the right tools coupled with solid programming is what makes it fast. However, it doesn't hurt that the servers are cooled with liquid cocaine.

Also, check out the [data dump schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678). A well-designed database and indexes are absolutely paramount to speed.

Comment: +1 - cocaine's a helluva drug. lol

Comment: that's all there is in their db? really?

Comment: @Jason: No, that's just some of what's in their db. There's obviously stuff that they haven't dumped out. But it's at least a taste.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think speed is referring to the *actual* speed of the site, but rather the time it requires to get answers. It's fast in the sense that you get answers to your questions quickly.

Comment: interesting. of course, as a programmer, when i hear that something is fast, i immediately thing page loads :)

Comment: I answered THIS question, but deleted it since someone told me I was answering the wrong question. Oh wells.